# Can't get simple if statement to work properly

Tags: c#

The problem is that whatever I try the `alert` only appears if *BOTH* are empty. If one of them has a value it will set the `resOne.Text` to `F`.

Here is the code:

```
private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // START OF AND OPERATION
        if (comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != "" || valueTwo.Text != "")
        {
            if (valueOne.Text == "T" || valueOne.Text == "1")
            {
                if (valueTwo.Text == "T" || valueTwo.Text == "1")
                {
                    resOne.Text = "T";
                    resOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                    resLineOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    resOne.Text = "F";
                    resOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                    resLineOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resOne.Text = "F";
                resOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                resLineOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
            }
        }
        else if (valueOne.Text == "" || valueTwo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Empty Fields");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I would replace `valueOne.Text != ""` with `! String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueOne.Text)` and likewise for valueTwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the main problem

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != "" || valueTwo.Text != "")
```

I assume your comboBox.Text always set to "AND"

then 
when 
valueOne.Text EMPTY, valueTwo.Text **NON-EMPTY** 
you fulfiled the second part of OR

```
valueTwo.Text != ""
```

when 
valueOne.Text **NON-EMPTY**, valueTwo.Text EMPTY 
you fulfiled the first part of OR

```
comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != ""
```

Therefore even **either one** has input, you can't go to Alert message.
Should be

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != "" && valueTwo.Text != "")
```

**ELSE IF** proceed for expression checking **only after** the **IF** expression is **FALSE**

Comment: Now when I see it, it's so obvious...
Thank you very much

Comment: if the desired ELSE IF statement can't be executed, it is just because IF statement or other ELSE IF statement(s) before it is TRUE. you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (valueOne.Text == "" || valueTwo.Text == "")

   MessageBox.Show("Error: Empty Fields");
}
else{
   // do something 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, let's simply it.

```
private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != "" || valueTwo.Text != "")
        {
            //SO This bit assumes everything has a value in
            if (valueOne.Text == "T" || valueOne.Text == "1" || valueTwo.Text == "T" || valueTwo.Text == "1)
            {
                    resOne.Text = "T";
                    resOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                    resLineOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                resOne.Text = "F";
                resOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                resLineOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
            }
        }
        else if (valueOne.Text == "" || valueTwo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Empty Fields");
        }
    }
```

How are you setting the text box's? That could be your issue. If they are not exactly `T` or `1` that will cause an issue. It might be worth trying the `Trim()` method to make sure there are no white spaces. It's not an issue with the IF statement.

If it sets the text box to "F" then there is nothing wrong with the following:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "AND" && valueOne.Text != "" || valueTwo.Text != "")
```

Your error occurs here:

```
if (valueOne.Text == "T" || valueOne.Text == "1" || valueTwo.Text == "T" || valueTwo.Text == "1)
```

I would suggest debugging it and stepping through :)

Answer (score 0):

Try determining empty fields first. I would also use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` for checking empty strings

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueOne.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmptyvalueTwo.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Empty Fields");
    }        
    else
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text.equals("AND"))
        {
            if (valueOne.Text.equals("T") || valueOne.Text.equals("1"))
            {
                if (valueTwo.Text.equals("T") || valueTwo.Text.equals("1"))
                {
                    resOne.Text = "T";
                    resOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                    resLineOne.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    resOne.Text = "F";
                    resOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                    resLineOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resOne.Text = "F";
                resOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                resLineOne.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
            }   
        }
    }
```